# Double quotes are not inserting into the database of phpMyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

```
$con=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);
$modified_message=rawurlencode($_POST['message']);

$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$query_savemsgids="insert into EmailCampaigns(cmpname,userid,cmpstartdatetime,subject) values('".$modified_message."',".$_SESSION['userid'].",DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL '07:00:10' HOUR_SECOND),'".$subject."')";
```

Comment: Did you start your `session_start();` before you used it?

Comment: Please use "\" before double quotes if you want to insert them in DB like in above code.

Comment: Yeah,I have used session_start(); also.

Answer (score 0):

escape your parameter using **mysqli_real_escape_string**. This function will escapes special characters like single quote,double quote, etc. in a string. It also helps to prevents sql injection.

```
//example
$subject=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['subject']);
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little more explanation about this function and how/why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: when I am storing with this functionality,it does not store the double quotes and &nbsp values inside the database

Comment: I have tried $subject=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['subject']);  function also but it's not inserting the quotes into the databae @sabeersas

Answer (score 0):

You should change your consult to this one.

`$date = mysql_real_escape_string("DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL '07:00:10' HOUR_SECOND)");`

```
$query_savemsgids="INSERT INTO EmailCampaigns(cmpname,userid,cmpstartdatetime,subject) VALUES('$modified_message', '$_SESSION[userid]', '$date' ,'$subject')";
```

And don't forget escape all users inputs with mysql_real_escape_string(*string*);

This will going to work with you.

Comment: My question is to insert the quotes into the database.Not the date

Comment: Well, then escape it with the first line of code.
`$date = mysql_real_escape_string("DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL '07:00:10' HOUR_SECOND)");`